# Get directory for library exe

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, working-directory

I have a C# VS2017 WPF application that references a library application which handles database access.

My objective is to track exception errors and be able to tell which application they are coming from.

To do so, I am trying to grab the directory path where the dll exists when an error occurs and to send it to the error log.

However, every time I only get the WPF directory and not the library application directory. I believe the WPF application being the start up application is the "executing" application.

I placed these directly in the library class but they all provide me the WPF executing directory:

```
string _BaseDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\","");

string attempt2 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

string attempt3 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the dll in the directory of your .exe file you need to make sure that the .dll is in the correct bin you are compiling and debugging into.   Can you just add this .dll as a reference to your project?